# How to show today's year and random 4 digit numbers at the same time?

Tags: javascript, html

Currently, I have 4 digit numbers showing randomly if I refresh the page. I tryna add the years infront of the 4 digit numbers but only 4 digit numbers still showing. Is there anyway to show the years in front of random numbers? (Example, 20221234).

```
<label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="refno">REF nos :</label>
  <div class="col-sm-4">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    now = new Date();
    randomNum = '';
    randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
    randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
    randomNum += now.getTime().toString().slice(-2);
    window.onload = function () {
        document.getElementById("refno").value = randomNum;
    }
    document.getElementById("refno").innerHTML = new Date().getFullYear();
</script>
    <p class="form-control-static" style="margin-top: -6px;">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="refno" name="refno" value="<?php echo $refno; ?>" disabled>
        
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-10"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you slicing a string instead of just using `.getYear()`?

Comment: input does NOT have `innerHTML` - so `document.getElementById("refno").innerHTML =` does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ***can't*** use `innerHTML` on an `input` tag. 
You can use `document.getElementById('someID').value` to replace the value.

```js
const now = new Date();
let randomNum = '';
randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
randomNum += Math.round(Math.random() * 9);
randomNum += now.getTime().toString().slice(-2);
document.getElementById("refno").value = `${new Date().getFullYear()}${randomNum}`;
```

```html
<label class="control-label col-sm-4" for="refno">REF nos :</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <br/>
  <p class="form-control-static" style="margin-top: -6px;">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="refno" name="refno" value="" disabled />
  </p>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-10"></div>
```